# Java JPA: How to keep sessions alive across HTTP requests?

Tags: spring, caching, jpa, httprequest

In a web application, I'm using JPA entities to persist (and retrieve) my domain objects to (and from) an underlying database.
**These JPA entities are kept "hot" in an in-memory cache structure (think of a `Map<UniqueID, Entity>`) for the whole running time of the web application**.

So I'm doing a request to my web application, an entity gets loaded from the repository. This entity gets put into the in-memory cache structure. For the whole lifetime of this request, I can happily access any fields of this entity. During this first request, also lazily-loading relationships to other entities works fine, even in my `View`: I'm successfully using the *Open-Session-in-View pattern* (via Spring's `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`).

The first request has ended.

I'm doing the next request to my web application. This request asks for another entity. **This entity is already in the in-memory cache structure**, so it gets loaded from there. From this entity, I try to access a field that should lazily-load relationships to other entities. This unfortunately causes the obnoxious  `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` (I'm using Hibernate as my underlying JPA implementation)

To my understanding, this exception stems from the fact that after the first request has ended, JPA/Hibernate has ended any JPA sessions, yet entities in my in-memory cache structure still expect any of these sessions to exist; at the moment that the next request causes to fire the mechanism for lazily-loading entities, the lazily-loading mechanism can't find any no-longer existing session.

What are solutions to my problem?

Comment: Could you make sure to load everything you need before the request ends, perhaps copying/cloning to new objects before caching? Generally it is best from a performance point of view to keep db transactions as short as possible.

Comment: @tofarr In my domain model, the JPA entity class points to other entities. So basically, imagine my entity class is `Person`, with a method `aPerson.getFriends()` returning a `Set<Person>`; a domain model instance becomes a network graph. I have the requirement to "hop" from `Person` to `Person` in successive HTTP requests. If I loaded every possible friend, and friends' friends and friends' friends' friends' and (...), then I would need to load every `Person` in my database just to be sure that I can access all data.

Answer (score 2):

1. One of solutions is to reattach the entity to session at the beginning of the second request using `Session.update()`.
2. Another solution is to use the [second level cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache) in Hibernate instead of your own solution. It should be much more reliable than any home-grown caching mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot keep sessions alive across HTTP requests because this would mean to keep the transaction open between requests.

I think the only solution (apart detecting yourself what is loaded and what is not) is to fetch the whole entity before putting it in your cache. IMHO you shouldn't put partially loaded objects in a cache. If you don't want to load the whole object the first time, you might use separate caches for the objects relationships.

If you want, you might also consider enabling Hibernate cache as proposed by @Adam, but I don't think it would work well with lady-loaded fields.

Comment: In JPA context, "session" and "transaction" are two separate concepts, aren't they? As much as I understand, a JPA session can be held active without affecting transaction semantics. So I would say the statement "this would mean to keep the transaction open between requests" isn't always true. .... Regarding the pre-fetching technique: My entities are quite recursive (think of `person.getFriends().getFriends()...`, so there is a big entity graph ). So eagerly fetching all entities "just in case they are needed" could mean there are thousands of thousands of objects required to be loaded.

Comment: You are right, a session is more like a connection to the database and can indeed span multiple transactions. I am not exactly sure of what happens to managed objects after closing the transaction since the entity manager cannot know the state of the database object anymore. Pay attention that sessions are not thread-safe though. Hibernate's second level cache would be worth a try, it should normally handle lazy-loaded collections transparently. However I am not sure it is possible to cache the relationship themselves (I recently tried with a simple OneToMany and I couldn't manage to cache it)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because your object is detached from current session. You have to re-attach this object to current session before assessing it

```
session.update(object);
```

You can read details [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView#The_problem)

Comment: `session.update(...)` seems to be Hibernate-specific. But I'm using JPA, therefore I need the corresponding JPA mechanism to do this. Also the questions now arise where and when I should re-attach the entity - preferably at the place and time the `LazyInitializationException` is thrown? (This maybe could be done inside the problematic entity method, in a catch block). And finally, I need to get hold of "that JPA `session` manager" in order to to call `session.update(this);` How can I inject "that JPA `session` manager" into my entity with Spring?

Comment: Okay, building upon what I have just commented, I successfully made a workaround with the suggested "session update" solution:... 1. Inject my problematic entity with `EntityManagerFactory emf`... 2. Inside the problematic entity, at every access to a possibly lazily-loading field, surround that field with a try-catch block... 3. `public Object problematicMethod() { try {...} catch (LazyInitializationException e) { JpaFacebookUser throwAway = emf.createEntityManager().merge(this); return throwAway.problematicMethod(); } }` ........... obviously, this is more of a hack than an elegant solution.

Comment: @Abdull yes, it's far from elegant solution, it's an *ugly* hack. If you use JPA then I would suggest using second level cache as I described above or refactoring the code so that it works with `EntityManager.merge()` instead of `Session.update()`, but it will reload data from DB anyway